# What is the meaning of role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.72' in history.log

Tags: apt, updates, mirrors

When checking two twin installs, same sources, same server, same location, sometimes updates are not the same or don't happen at the same time.

My understanding of this is that its linked to [phased updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates).

In history.log, I can see that type of line :
`Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.72'`

From one install to the other, the sender will be different (i.e `sender='1.77'`)

My assumption there is that this sender ID difference is a marker for phased updates.

Am I correct or does it have a totally different meaning?